# How should I Unit test Angular2 components and modules that has imported other modules (and components)

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular-material2

I have spent a while getting the hang of modules in Angular2 and really like them but I am a little uncertain as to best approach for testing both my modules and the components within. (I also realise that my app.component can and probably should be broken out more but for now it is helpful while learning the testing framework to be a little more complex)

For example this is my app.module:

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { AUTH_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2-jwt';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ComponentsModule } from './components';
import { MaterialModule} from './material';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ViewsModule } from './+views';

import { rootReducer } from './dataStore';

import { CurrentUserModel } from './models/current-user'


const appStore = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

const APP_DECLARATIONS = [
  AppComponent
];

const APP_PROVIDERS = [
  { provide: 'AppStore', useValue: appStore },
  CurrentUserModel
];

@NgModule({
  imports:[
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,// here as well as in our Views Module because of router-outlet
    ViewsModule,
    MaterialModule, // here as well as in our Views & componet Module because used in App componet
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  declarations: APP_DECLARATIONS,
  bootstrap:[AppComponent],
  providers: APP_PROVIDERS,
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

and this is what my app.component looks like:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  styleUrls:['app.component.scss'],
  template: `
  <md-toolbar>
  <!--  <i class="material-icons demo-toolbar-icon">menu</i> -->
    <span class="toolbar-brand">Franks</span>
    <span *ngIf="searchActive" role="search" class="fill-remaining-space">
        <span class="search-input-container flex flex-1">
          <i class="material-icons search-link">search</i>
          <input class="search-input" placeholder="Search" type="text" id="searchInput" #searchInput (keyup.esc)="exitSearch($event)"/>
        </span>
    </span>
    <i *ngIf="searchActive" class="material-icons right selectable" (click)="exitSearch($event)">close</i>

    <span *ngIf="!searchActive" class="fill-remaining-space">

    </span>
    <span *ngIf="!searchActive" role="navmenu">
      <span class="hlink" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">home</span>
      <span class="hlink" routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="active">Profile</span>
      <span class="hlink" routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</span>
      <span class="hlink" routerLink="/signup" routerLinkActive="active">Sign Up</span>
      <i class="material-icons search-link" (click)="activeSearch($event)">search</i>
    </span>
  </md-toolbar>
  <div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('searchInput') searchInputRef;

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if(this.searchActive && this.searchInputRef){
      console.log(this.searchInputRef);       
      this.searchInputRef.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }
  searchActive: boolean;
  constructor(public router: Router) {
    this.searchActive = false;
  }

  activeSearch(event):void {
    this.searchActive = true;
  }

  exitSearch(event) : void {
    this.searchActive = false;
  }
}
```

So I know I can potentially mock out all the Components with for example the `MaterialComponents` (this is just a wrapper module for the material components) within my tests but this seems a little tedious. Is that my only options and if so does it make sense to make creating a mock of components when creating the components part of the process.

for informational purposes this is what my material module looks like and my views and components modules are similar:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Material
import { MdCardModule } from '@angular2-material/card';
import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';
import { MdInputModule } from '@angular2-material/input';
import { MdToolbarModule } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';
import { MdListModule } from '@angular2-material/list';
import { MdIconModule, MdIconRegistry } from '@angular2-material/icon';



const MATERIAL_UI_MODULES = [
  MdCardModule,
  MdButtonModule,
  MdInputModule,
  MdToolbarModule,
  MdIconModule,
  MdListModule
]
const MATERIAL_UI_REGISTRIES = [
  MdIconRegistry
]

@NgModule({
  imports:[
    ...MATERIAL_UI_MODULES,
  ],
  providers: MATERIAL_UI_REGISTRIES,
  exports:[
    ...MATERIAL_UI_MODULES,
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I eventually figured out how to do this and this is my current solution:

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import { TestBed, inject, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { Component,ViewChild, AfterViewChecked  } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location, CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule} from './material';

@Component({
  template: '<div></div>'
})
class DummyComponent {
}


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('component: TestComponent', function () {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
         { path: 'profile', component: DummyComponent },
         { path: 'login', component: DummyComponent },
         { path: 'signup', component: DummyComponent },
         { path: '', component: DummyComponent }
       ]),
       MaterialModule
      ],
      declarations: [ AppComponent, DummyComponent ]
    });
  });

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should be navigate to correct url for each option in navmenu',
    async(inject([Router, Location], (router: Router, location: Location) => {

    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('span.hlink[routerLink="/profile"]')).nativeElement.click();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toEqual('/profile');
      expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('span.hlink[routerLink="/profile"]')).classes['active']).toBeTruthy();
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('span.hlink.active').length).toEqual(1)

      fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('span.hlink[routerLink="/login"]')).nativeElement.click();
      return fixture.whenStable();
    }).then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toEqual('/login');
      expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('span.hlink[routerLink="/login"]')).classes['active']).toBeTruthy();
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('span.hlink.active').length).toEqual(1)

      fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('span.hlink[routerLink="/signup"]')).nativeElement.click();
      return fixture.whenStable();
    }).then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toEqual('/signup');
      expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('span.hlink[routerLink="/signup"]')).classes['active']).toBeTruthy();
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('span.hlink.active').length).toEqual(1)

      fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('span.hlink[routerLink="/"]')).nativeElement.click();
      return fixture.whenStable();
    }).then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toEqual('/');
      expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('span.hlink[routerLink="/"]')).classes['active']).toBeTruthy();
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('span.hlink.active').length).toEqual(1)
    });

  })));
});
```